# Prove the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln(n)(\ln(\ln(n)))^2}$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I need to prove the series $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln(n)(\ln(\ln(n)))^2}$$ converges.

I cant use comparison test, since if I take away any term in denominator I know it will diverge. Any help please?

Comment: Hint: Condensation.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the integral test?

Comment: Yes, I can use integral test

Comment: Alternative hint: integral test. EDIT: ninja'd, apparently.

Comment: @ kar677: So integrate $1/(x\log x (\log(\log x))^2)$

Comment: I tried, but I can't see antiderivative...

Comment: @kar677 -- you only spent 1 minute on your "try". It is in fact an immediate anti-derivative, but it may require more than one minute  of reflection.  Try substituting $u=\log x$.

Comment: @kar677 The series is convergent. Please, see my answers below. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a closed form for this series?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** Since the general term is a *positive and decreasing sequence*, by the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), your series behaves as the following integral:
$$
\int_3^{\infty}\frac{{\rm d} x}{x \ln x \:(\ln(\ln x))^2}. \tag1
$$ By the change of variable $$u=\ln(\ln x), \quad du=\dfrac{dx}{x \ln x },$$ we easily have

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_3^{\infty}\frac{{\rm d} x}{x \ln x \:(\ln(\ln x))^2} \mathrm dx=\int_{\ln(\ln 3)}^{\infty}\frac{{\rm d} u}{u^2}
> =\left[ -\frac{1}{u}\right]_{\ln(\ln 3)}^{\infty}
> =\frac1{\ln(\ln 3)}.
> \end{align}
> $$

Your initial series is **convergent**.

**Edit.** Thanks to user109899's remark, we have singled out the term coming from $n=2$.

Comment: I think there's a little error; the integrand is positive over the entire interval, but your result is negative. In fact, the integral probably diverges due to the pole at $x=e$. I suggest to ignore the first term and start with $n=3$ in order to prove it rigourosly.

Comment: @user109899 Thank you very much for your comment above!

Comment: You're welcome. Great answers by the way! +1

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.** You may apply the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) since *the sequence is positive and decreasing*:

> $\sum_n a_n$ converges **if and only if** $\sum_n 2^n \:a_{2^n}$ converges.

By setting $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{1}{n \ln(n)(\ln(\ln(n)))^2} $, we easily get
$$\sum_n 2^n \:a_{2^n}=\sum_{n\geq2} \frac{2^n}{2^n \cdot n \ln2\cdot(\ln n +\ln 2)^2}\leq \frac1{\ln 2}\sum_{n\geq2} \frac{1}{n \ln^2 n}.$$
The latter series may be treated in the same way, you may consider
$$
\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{2^n }{2^n \ln^2 (2^n)}= \frac1{\ln^2 2}\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{1}{n^2 }.
$$
Your initial series is **convergent**.